# How to read child node in xml

Tags: sql-server, xml

Does anyone know how to read child nodes of xml in sql ?

I am trying it hard but not able to get it ??

below is my sample xml

```
<RequisitionRequest>
<Authentication>
  <PartnerID>Provided By Client</PartnerID>
  <SharedSecret>Provided By client</SharedSecret>
  <PartnerVersion>client</PartnerVersion>
  <IntegrationVersion>Provided By Agile1</IntegrationVersion>
  <ClientDBKey>Provided By Agile1</ClientDBKey>
  <RequestorID>J234</RequestorID>
</Authentication>

<JobPosting>
  <ClientReferenceID>C112</ClientReferenceID>
  <Requisition>
    <LanguageID>1</LanguageID>
  </Requisition>
</JobPosting>

<Authentication>
  <PartnerID>Provided By client</PartnerID>
  <SharedSecret>Provided By client</SharedSecret>
  <PartnerVersion>client</PartnerVersion>
  <IntegrationVersion>Provided By client</IntegrationVersion>
  <ClientDBKey>Provided By client</ClientDBKey>
  <RequestorID>33234</RequestorID>
</Authentication>

<JobPosting>
  <ClientReferenceID>C100</ClientReferenceID>
  <Requisition>
    <LanguageID>2</LanguageID>
  </Requisition>
</JobPosting>
<RequisitionRequest>
```

and want to pull the details of  PartnerID, SharedSecret, PartnerVersion, IntegrationVersion, ClientDBKey, RequestorID, ClientReferenceID, LanguageID

Below is my cursor

```
declare cur cursor local fast_forward for
SELECT
COALESCE([Table].[Column].value('( ./ Authentication/PartnerID)[1]', 'int'),0) as 'PartnerID',
[Table].[Column].value('(./ Authentication/SharedSecret) [1]', 'varchar(max)') as '  SharedSecret',               
[Table].[Column].value(' (./ Authentication/PartnerVersion)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as '          PartnerVersion',
[Table].[Column].value('( ./ Authentication/IntegrationVersion) [1]', 'varchar(max)') as ' IntegrationVersion',
[Table].[Column].value(' ( ./ JobPosting / ClientReferenceID) [1]', 'varchar(max)') as ' ClientReferenceID',
[Table].[Column].value('(./ Authentication/ClientDBKey) [1]', 'varchar(max)') as ' ClientDBKey ',
[Table].[Column].value('(./ Authentication/RequestorID) [1]', 'varchar(max)') as ' RequestorID ',
[Table].[Column].value('( ./ Authentication/JobPosting/Requisition/LanguageID)[1]', 'int'),0) as    'LanguageID',
FROM @input.nodes('/ RequisitionRequest') as [Table]([Column])

open cur
while 1=1
begin
fetch cur into @PartnerID, @SharedSecret,    @PartnerVersion,@IntegrationVersion,@ClientReferenceID,@DBKey,@RequestorID,@LanguageID
if @@fetch_status <> 0 break
print @PartnerID
print @SharedSecret
print @PartnerVersion
print @IntegrationVersion
print @ClientReferenceID
print @DBKey
print @RequestorID
print @LanguageID
end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Comment: What do you mean, "read in SQL?" Is this in a database record?  What type of database?  What does this have to do with asp.net? Please be SPECIFIC.

Comment: apologize for the incorrect tag. I want to do this sql. I am trying to insert records in database table through stored procedure. Currently I am looping xml in using cursor where I am getting only one record

Comment: Yes this is a database records. Read means; read all child nodes and insert there value in the database.

Comment: If you show you looping cursor version perhaps someone can spot why you only get one record. As the question is now it just looks like you want someone else to write the code for you.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I have update my cursor version. So, now can you please tell me where I am going wrong ??

Comment: The XML you have posted is not a match the the query you have posted. The query has syntax errors so that could not be the code you are using. However there is an apparent reason for this to only process one row. You don't have a loop anywhere that loops over the cursor. Skip the cursor and first verify that the query you have actually returns all the rows you need and then think about what you want to do with them. Perhaps a cursor is not necessary at all.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Ok fine. I have corrected the code. If cursor is not the option then what should I try ? The data which is present in 'Authentication' tag; I want the multiple results for the same.

Comment: No you have not. Your query is invalid and the data types are wrong. You clearly have not executed you code with the XML you have provided. But you did fix the cursor. Why do you need a cursor? What do you intend to do with the data you extract.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson. I just want to insert these values in there respective individual columns by validating the value of each tag. If Of not cursor then what should I use ?

Comment: You should use `insert into YourTable(Col1, Col2) select Col1, Col2 from YourSource`. Have a look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189872(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it this way:

```
 XElement element = XElement.Parse(XML);

var Result = from a in element.Descendants("Authentication")
             select new
                   {
                     PartnerID = a.Element("PartnerID").Value,
                     ...............................
                     .............................
                   };
```

### UPDATED:

```
var Result = from a in element.Descendants("Authentication")
             from b in element.Descendants("JobPosting")
             from c in b.Descendants("Requisition")
             select new
                   {
                     PartnerID = a.Element("PartnerID").Value,
                     SharedSecret = a.Element("SharedSecret").Value,
                     PartnerVersion = a.Element("PartnerVersion").Value,
                     IntegrationVersion = a.Element("IntegrationVersion").Value,
                     ClientDBKey = a.Element("ClientDBKey").Value,
                     RequestorID = a.Element("RequestorID").Value,
                     ClientReferenceID = b.Element("ClientReferenceID").Value,
                     LanguageID = c.Element("LanguageID").Value

                   };
```

[Working DEMO FIDDLE Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pazitW)

Answer (score 0):

0) you're question is not clear. however - if you want to read it in c#  (assuming the data is retrieved from sql - or not)

1) You forgot to close the last tag.

2) Here's the full working example :

```
void Main()
{
    string g=@"<RequisitionRequest>
    <Authentication>
        <PartnerID>Provided By Client</PartnerID>
        <SharedSecret>Provided By client</SharedSecret>
        <PartnerVersion>client</PartnerVersion>
        <IntegrationVersion>Provided By Agile1</IntegrationVersion>
        <ClientDBKey>Provided By Agile1</ClientDBKey>
        <RequestorID>J234</RequestorID>
    </Authentication>
    <JobPosting>
        <ClientReferenceID>C112</ClientReferenceID>
        <Requisition>
            <LanguageID>1</LanguageID>
        </Requisition>
    </JobPosting>

    <Authentication>
        <PartnerID>Provided By client</PartnerID>
        <SharedSecret>Provided By client</SharedSecret>
        <PartnerVersion>client</PartnerVersion>
        <IntegrationVersion>Provided By client</IntegrationVersion>
        <ClientDBKey>Provided By client</ClientDBKey>
        <RequestorID>33234</RequestorID>
    </Authentication>
    <JobPosting>
        <ClientReferenceID>C100</ClientReferenceID>
        <Requisition>
            <LanguageID>2</LanguageID>
        </Requisition>
    </JobPosting>
</RequisitionRequest>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(g);
var dict = doc.Root.Elements();


                 var s=new [] {"SharedSecret","PartnerID","IntegrationVersion"/*...*/}.ToList();
                 foreach (var element in dict )
                {  
                    if ( element.Name=="Authentication")
                    {
                       s.ForEach(f=>Console.WriteLine (element.Element(f).Value));
                    }
                }
}
```

Result :

```
Provided By client
Provided By Client
Provided By Agile1
Provided By client
Provided By client
Provided By client
```

Comment: apologize for the incorrect tag. I want to this in sql server in stored procedure. I have passed the above xml to SP and then want to insert records in database table using the xml.